# How to Launch default media player by clicking a button from my app

Tags: android

I have three buttons on my app next, play/pause and back buttons. By clicking on play button I wants to play song from mobile default audio player of mobile and by clicking next and previous buttons I wants to switch songs. Kindly guide how can I achieve this

Comment: get all audio song in mobile directory and added into a list. Then play song using media player.Next and previous button to changing the list item position

Comment: check out this repo : https://github.com/OxygenCobalt/Auxio

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("Your mp3 file url");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

video player:

```
File file = new File("fileUri");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

and audio player:

```
File file = new File("fileUri");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```